# jQuery Mobile PhoneGap XML parsing ( iOS )

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova, simulator

I am using PhoneGap, jQuery mobile in Xcode. I have a local xml (data.xml) file with the following data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RecentTutorials>
<Tutorial author="The Reddest">
    <Title>Silverlight and the Netflix API</Title>
    <Categories>
        <Category>Tutorials</Category>
        <Category>Silverlight 2.0</Category>
        <Category>Silverlight</Category>
        <Category>C#</Category>
        <Category>XAML</Category>
    </Categories>
    <Date>1/13/2009</Date>
</Tutorial>
<Tutorial author="The Hairiest">
    <Title>Cake PHP 4 - Saving and Validating Data</Title>
    <Categories>
        <Category>Tutorials</Category>
        <Category>CakePHP</Category>
        <Category>PHP</Category>
    </Categories>
    <Date>1/12/2009</Date>
</Tutorial>
<Tutorial author="The Tallest">
    <Title>Silverlight 2 - Using initParams</Title>
    <Categories>
        <Category>Tutorials</Category>
        <Category>Silverlight 2.0</Category>
        <Category>Silverlight</Category>
        <Category>C#</Category>
        <Category>HTML</Category>
    </Categories>
    <Date>1/6/2009</Date>
</Tutorial>
<Tutorial author="The Fattest">
    <Title>Controlling iTunes with AutoHotkey</Title>
    <Categories>
        <Category>Tutorials</Category>
        <Category>AutoHotkey</Category>
    </Categories>
    <Date>12/12/2008</Date>
</Tutorial>
```

And I have the following code in my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
                   success: function(xml){
                   $(xml).find("Tutorial").each(function()
                                                {

                                $("#output").append($(this).attr("author") + "<br />");
                                                });


                   }
            });
            });

            </script>


            <script type="text/javascript">
                function parseXml(xml)
                {

                    $(xml).find("Tutorial").each(function()
                                                 {
                                                 $("#output").append($(this).attr("author") + "<br />");
                                                 });


                }    
            </script>


</head> 

<body> 
    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>The title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" id="output">

  <--!  XML DATA SUPPOSED TO BE DISPLAYED HERE BUT I GOT NOTHING HERE  -->

        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h4>The Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /header -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

I am using Xcode for the output in the iPhone simulator and its not displaying anything inside the content which is supposed to be displayed.

Where did I do mistake or do I need third-party xml parser ?

Any suggestions would be a great help.
Thanks

Comment: Two things come to mind. First, you seem to be using jQuery Mobile. When you do, it is NOT recommended to use document.ready. Please see the JQM Docs on Events. They talk about this specifically.

Comment: Secondly - did you try adding console.log() messages in your code to see if a) it found the xml and b) if $(xml).find("Tutorial") is finding stuff?

Comment: Hi Raymond, thanks for the reply. Can not we use document.ready on jquery mobile framework? I did not know that. I will check the JQM Docs in details. And also thanks for the suggestion to check console.log() message too. I will check that as well. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this and it worked perfectly for me.
Instead of using

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

I wrote the following:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {

// AJAX code goes here

});
<script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-
1.0.min.js"></script>
```

Its important to note that this code should be between the jquery-core and jquery-mobile link as I did above.